# Change stroke color of MUI SvgIcon using custom SVG

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I can successfully change the fill color of custom SVG's by using `SvgIcon`.

```js
import { ReactComponent as MyIcon } from '../my_custom_logo.svg';
<SvgIcon component={MyIcon} inheritViewBox color="primary" />
```

As I want to change the stroke color as well, is there a way to set another `SvgIcon` prop and not by using `sx={{ fill: theme.palette.primary.main }}` to achieve that?

This is the working version by using the sx property:

```js
import { ReactComponent as MyIcon } from '../my_custom_logo.svg';
<SvgIcon component={MyIcon} inheritViewBox color="primary" sx={{ stroke: theme.palette.primary.main }} />
```

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest doing that with styled from MUI

```
import { ReactComponent as MyIcon } from '../my_custom_logo.svg';
import { styled } from '@mui/material/styles';
import SvgIcon from '@mui/material/SvgIcon';

// Define a styled component for your SvgIcon
const StyledSvgIcon = styled(SvgIcon)(({theme}) => ({
// Define your CSS styles here
stroke: theme.palette.primary.main,
}));

// Use your custom styled component
<StyledSvgIcon component={MyIcon} color="primary" />
```

You can also add another prop by overriding the component using styled too like this for example :

```
 const StyledSvgIcon = styled(SvgIcon,{ shoudlFormwardProp: (prop) => 
 prop !== "customStroke"})<{customStroke?: boolean}>(({customStroke,theme}) => 
 ({
     stroke: customStroke ? theme.palette.primary.main : undefined
 }))
```

then you can apply the stroke you want just but calling the component like this :

```
<StyledSvgIcon component={MyIcon} color="primary" customStroke/>
```